# In Jython, how can I raise a Python Exception, not a java.lang.Exception?

Tags: jython, wlst

Python and Jython newbie here.

I am passably familiar with how to raise exceptions in normal Python.

However, in the Jython environment I find myself in ([`WLST`](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLSTG/using_wlst.htm#WLSTG119)), if I do:

```
raise Exception("hello")
```

...then it appears to raise a `java.lang.Exception`:

```
wls:/offline> raise Exception("hello")
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in ?
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

java.lang.Exception: java.lang.Exception: hello
wls:/offline>
```

How can I raise a Python `Exception` in this environment?  Or, at least: why is it a `java.lang.Exception` that is raised here?

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, I can do this:

```
from exceptions import Exception as PythonException
```

Then I can do this:

```
raise Exception('This will be a java.lang.Exception.')
raise PythonException('This will be a "native" Python exception.')
```